# Symfony form works in twig file but not with extended layout

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I created a mailform in Symfony2 framework which works but when i add the twig extend method it doesn't work.

I got stuck here so hopefully you can help me!

The form works with the following twig code:

```
{% block content %}
    {{form(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't work with the following twig code:

```
{% extends 'TMCBundle::layout.html.twig' %}


{% block content %}
    {{form(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT: Sorry, i forgot to tell: the submit button won't work, so the form action is not triggered.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Is there an error?

Comment: Is there `{% block content %}` in you layout?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it seems that the submit button won't work, there's no reaction. But when i delete the "{% extends ... %}" the form gets submitted (and a mail is sent...)

Comment: yeah the {% block content %} is in my layout, so everything gets rendered like it should. I also tried it with "{% block dynamic%}", and also this one gets rendered, but the same problem.

Comment: you've probably got some javascript included in that layout that listens in for the submit button being clicked.

Comment: Thats it Derick F! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was Derick F's answer: I got a javascript that listened to the form...!
Thanks!